# How do I change a text label based upon a combobox selection?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, label

I have a combobox which has 10 entries in them and when you click one I want the  Select entry  to change based upon which one the user selects in the combobox. I have tried something similar to this but it doesnt seem to work.

```
    if (document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex = '0')
        {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice1';}

            else if(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex = '1')
                {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice2';}

                    else(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex = '2')
                        {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice3';}
```

The problem is, whichever cam I click is always reverting to the last one giving me 'choice3' as my label for all 10 entries. Any help? I havent finished the code as these arent even working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code have 2 main problems.

1. For equality comparison you must use '==' not '=' . '=' will change the value
2. The last 'else' must have an 'if' keyword

The correct is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function select() {

   if (document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '0')
        {document.getElementById('labelname').value ='choice1';}

            else if(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '1')
                {document.getElementById('labelname').value ='choice2';}

                    else if(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '2')
                        {document.getElementById('labelname').value ='choice3';} 

}
</script>       
</head>     

<body>

<select id="label">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<button onclick="select()">Select</button>

<input type="text" id="labelname" />

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: That's it! it was the last else if! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer:

Change

```
{document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML=='choice1';}
```

to

```
{document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice1';}
```

Don't use `==` when you want to assign something to something

Can you provide details on which we can simulate this one? Include your html snippet and javascript.  here http://jsbin.com/

Comment: {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice1';}

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '0')
        {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice1';}

            else if(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '1')
                {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice2';}

                    else(document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex == '2')
                        {document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML='choice3';}
```

Try this. use `==` to check value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selValue = document.getElementById('label').value;
document.getElementById('labelname').innerHTML = selValue;
```

For this to work "label" must look like this:

```
<select id="label">
    <option>Name one</option>
    <option>Name two</option>
    <option>Name three</option>
</select>
```

`.value` will give you inner text in `<option selected>text in here is .value</option>`

UPD. JS:

```
  var index = document.getElementById('label').selectedIndex;
  var labelName = document.getElementById('labelName');

  switch(index) {
    case 0:
      labelName.innerHTML = "cam1";
      break;

    case 1:
      labelName.innerHTML = "cam2";
      break;
  }
```

If you need more cases, just add as in example, `case 2: ... case 3: ...` and so on

p.s. `switch() {}` is much more beautiful than hierarchy of `if ... else`

Comment: I want it to be different to the option value though.

Comment: Updated. Add cases for all your values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/spSAs/ here is working example. Used to jsFidle, so I've made it there.